# Supported characters in xsd pattern

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have the following in the xsd, the pattern says it should be "\d{10}", does this mean:

- it supports only 10 characters(i.e digits, alphabets, special
  character)
- it supports only 10 digits(i.e only 0 to 9)

Following is the xml:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="zip">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="\d{10}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the schema language and its regular expressions, `\d` stands for Unicode decimal digits, that includes the ASCII digits `0`, `1`, ..., `9`, but also a lot of other digits of other scripts, see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm. If you only want to allow ASCII digits then use `[0-9]{10}`.

Comment: K..so it means always digits..but supports other unicode..great..!! There were lot of answers but they were not very clear about it